With NETCONF over TLS using sysrepo/netopeer2, how do I disable CRL checking?
I'm running a netconf server using the sysrepo/netopeer2 Docker image.
I have updated the tls_truststore.xml, tls_keystore.xml and tls_listen.xml with my certificate data and I have a post-install script that loads these files via sysrepocfg before the netopeer2-server has started.
My problem is that the server certificate provided to me includes a "CRL Destination Point" that is unreachable by the netconf server, so all TLS connection attempts fail after some time.
Is there a way to disable the CRL checking?
I have tried adding this to my tls_listen.xml (thanks to ChatGPT):
<tls>
  <crl_check>false</crl_check>

I have tried adding this to my openssl.cnf file (thanks to Phind AI):
crl_check = false

In both of those cases, I expected the CRL check to be skipped entirely.  The change to the openssl.cnf file had no effect at all.  The change to the tls_listen.xml file preventing any TLS connections from being made.
